# How to reformat cell without moving table?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm making a social media app, and the only way to make the cell update when the user adds a like to the cell is by using...

```
self.table.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)
```

Except when it does that it reformats the cell because the like button title turns into unlike and the table is sometimes pushed up which is really annoying. Does anyone know what I should do? Please leave a comment if more information is needed. Thanks. (:

Here is my cellForRowAtIndexPath method which sets the like button initially to either Like or Unlike...

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            if PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId != nil {
                if (post["likers"] as! NSMutableArray).containsObject(PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!) {
                    postCellObj.likeButton.setTitle("Unlike", forState: .Normal)
                } else {
                    postCellObj.likeButton.setTitle("Like", forState: .Normal)
                }

            } else {
                postCellObj.likeButton.setTitle("Like", forState: .Normal)

            }
        }

        postCellObj.numberOfLikes.text = (post["likers"] as! [String]).count.description + " Likes"
```

Comment: Sounds like your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method isn't written correctly.

Comment: @rmaddy Just added the part where I set the like button initially to like or unlike. Am I doing anything wrong?